# How can I count in Firebase the collections in a document

Tags: javascript, firebase, collections, count, document

I know how to count how many Documents are in a collection in Firebase but how does it work the other way around. I have several collections in a document and I need to find out how many. (In my example it would be 2)

My Setup:

```
Collection     Document      Collections  Documents
[USERID]   -   [TESTS]   -   [1]   -      [ANSWERS]
                                          [RESULTS]
                         
                             [2]   -      [ANSWERS]
                                          [RESULTS]
```

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
let refTest_1 = db.collection(USERID).doc('TESTS')
let testData_1
refTest_1.get().then(doc => {
  //testData_1 = doc.data()
  testData_1 = doc.size
}).then(function() {
  //console.log(Object.keys(testData_1).length)
  console.log(testData_1)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("Error: " + error.message)
})
```

Does anybody know how this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Firebase Web Client has no implemented method to get all collections of an object. You can take a look at the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document). In Node.js you could just use the `.listCollections()` method as described in the same documentation. Afterwards, you would have to get all the documents in the collections and count them manually in js.

Comment: Thanks EricHier for the quick answer. Since I'm pretty new to the Webdevelopment, just one question, even at the risk of making a fool of myself. How can I implement a nore.js code in vuejs? Do you know that?

Comment: To accomplish this, you would have to set up a backend with an https server. You could use firebase functions for that - I think it is the simplest way to do so. You could take a look at the according documentation. :)